# Which interface should I implement to have parse method

Tags: java, xml, parsing, interface, methods

I'm working with webservices. I have a java object defined for the request. I'd like to create a java object of this type from a String or a XmlObject. Which interface should I implement to use the method parse to do this?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Won't you be better off using some kind of serialization/deserialization library such as [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) or something

Comment: +1, only I would suggest using a JAXB implementation such as MOXy (http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) or Metro (https://jaxb.dev.java.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own interface :)

```
public interface Parser<E>
{
  E parse(String sourceString);
}
```